# Translation of "I would be interested to know how it goes."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How can I say

> I would be interested to know how it goes.

Would it be

> Ich würde interessiert sein zu wissen, wie es läuft.

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not "Ich würde interessiert sein" but "Es würde mich interessieren":

> Es würde mich interessieren zu wissen wie es läuft.

But this sounds rough. This is better:

> Ich würde gerne wissen wie es läuft.

Comment: Sehe das auch so, dass interessieren und wissen zusammen zuviel wäre. Aber natürlich könnte man dann auch sagen "Mich würde interessieren, wie es läuft." Sollte da nicht übrigens immer ein Komma stehen?

Comment: @OregonGhost Hier bin ich mir sicher, ein Komma muss hin.

Comment: oder "Ich wüsste gern, wie es läuft."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use clear German language than there is no "I would ...". It is too subjunctive. 
It may sound rude for forreigners but: just say what you want instead of saying what you "would want". So say like Hubert wrote:

```
Ich würde gern wissen, wie es läuft.
```

"Gern" is the only needed polite part of the sentence.

An even less formal version is to ask directly instead to say that you are interested:

```
"Wie läuft's?"
```

or

```
"Funktioniert's?"
```

(in case you meant something like "does it work?".

Comment: Although I can partially agree with you, many people say "Ich würde gern wissen." It's like many people say "Ich wollte dir noch schnell gratulieren" instead of "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" ;)

Comment: Many people saying it, doesn't make it right. The right answer to "ich wollte Dir noch schnell gratulieren" is "Why don't you do it instead of telling me you would".